# vb.net Array.Find string by Length

Tags: arrays, vb.net, find

i have an array of string like this :

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

i know how to get the index of one letter in the array string 
like this

```
Dim itemindex As String = Array.IndexOf(myarr, "C")
TextBox2.Text = itemindex
```

It return for me the number 2

but i want to know how to do it in the Reverse way like if i give the index **2** i want it to return for me the letter **C** ?

i want to do that for tow array withe the same size
one in the listbox if i select one item i want it to return for me the item in the second array that have the same index number

Comment: `i give the index 2 i want it to return for me the letter C ` would be:  `Dim find = myArr(2)`  common ordinary array reference by index.  No idea how the length from the title comes into play

Comment: @Plutonix
`Dim charc As String = ListBox2.SelectedItem`
        
      

  `Select Case charc`
           ` Case charc`
                `charc = myarr(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)`
        `End Select`
        `TextBox1.Text = charc`
work for me thank you so match !!!!

Comment: it looks like listbox.selectedindex would work and without the implicit data type conversion

Answer (score 1):

Just use myArr(2) to access the 3rd element in the array.

Or to get a character from a string, use SubString e.g.

```
s.Substring(startIndex, length)
```

Length for you would be 1, if you're looking for a single character.